# problem to applied color by class in angular material component

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I had angular material 10.2.5 in my angular 10 project.
I includes the theme by adding this line

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

in my style.css
I create a component and i use a material button with primary color ,but my button color is not applied.

```
 <button mat-button color="primary">Toogle</button>
```

[image]
the button color must be blue

Any idea ?

Comment: `button { color: blue; }` - simple :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't overwrite the angular material theme, unless you go through the material CSS to create a new color palette.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to import the angular-material theme in your styles.css file. First you have to add the angular-material to your angular project by running this command in CLI.

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Now you can import the angular-material file in styles.css by

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

For the reference you can visit https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started